# Computing smallest eigenvalue for positive semi-definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods

Given $A \in\mathbb{S}^n$ positive semi-definite matrix where

$$ \lambda_1 \geq \cdots \geq \lambda_{n-1} > \lambda_n $$

I am trying to come up with an algorithm that uses the [Power Iteration Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) such that given $\epsilon>0$ will find a vector such that

$$ \lambda_n \leq x^TAx \leq \lambda_n + \epsilon $$
where $$\lambda_n >0$$

In other words I am trying to get the eigenvector relating to the smallest eigenvalue of the matrix $A$.

I saw the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271864/how-to-compute-the-smallest-eigenvalue-using-the-power-iteration-algorithm) referring to **positive definite**, however, since eigenvalues can be equal to zero, the methods suggested such as shifting the eigenvalues won't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: There's nothing to stop you from applying the answer to the previous question.  If there's an eigenvalue strictly greater than 0, then you can apply the approach suggested by the answers to the previous question.  If all of the eigenvalues are 0, then any vector will do.

Comment: @BrianBorchers The question is if I have some (not strictly all) eigenvalues equal to 0, then when shifting them, wouldn't the the "zero eigenvalues" have the largest magnitude thus be perceived as the smallest?

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is positive semi-definite, then $A+I$ is positive definite with the same eigenvectors, since
$$
Av=\lambda v\iff (A+I)v=(\lambda+1)v.
$$
Now, apply the power iteration method on $A+I$.

**Edit**

In case the power iteration method yields only the largest eigenvalue, perform the following transformation $$(A+I)^{-1}.$$

Comment: Suppose $\lambda_n = 0$, we first shift it by one to get $\lambda_n = 1$, when applying the power iteration method, the algorithm will return $\lambda_n = 1$,, and this isn't what I am looking for.
Am I missing something?

Comment: The power iteration method gives you the largest eigenvalue and the corresponding eigenvector. Since the eigenvectors of $A$ and $aA+bI$ are the same for $a\ne 0$, applying power iteration method gives you the eigenvectors of $A$ and the largest $a\lambda +b$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, Same is true about $(aA+bI)^{-1}$.