# Finding the (smallest) hypersphere that encloses a known ellipsoid without computing eigenvalues

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, geometry, spectral-theory, quadrics

I am working on the problem of finding the (smallest) hypersphere that encloses a known ellipsoid, with possible equality on the ellipsoid's largest semi-axes, without computing any eigenvalues.  I am attempting to set about this as follows:

Let
$$
(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0)^\intercal \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0) = 1
$$
describe the ellipsoid, $E$, concerned.  To be explicit, $\mathbf{A}$ is symmetric positive definite and nonsingular.  Then by observing that
$$
r_0 := r(\mathbf{A}^{-1})
$$
where $r(\mathbf{A}^{-1})$ is the spectral radius of $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$, $\sqrt{r_0}$ represents the length of the largest semi-axis of $E$.  Therefore the hypersphere $C$ described by
$$
(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0)^\intercal(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0) = r_0
$$
is exactly the smallest hypersphere that encloses $E$ with equality occurring at the end-point of each semi-axis of $E$ having $r_0$ as its length.

Now, to avoid computing any eigenvalues I am considering the formula of Gelfand which states that for any matrix $\mathbf{M}$ and consistent matrix norm $\|\cdot\|$,
$$
r(\mathbf{M}) \leq \|\mathbf{M}^k\|^{\frac{1}{k}} =: n_k(\mathbf{M})
$$
for all $k$.  Therefore any hypersphere $C_k$ described by
$$
(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0)^\intercal(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0) = n_k(\mathbf{A}^{-1})
$$
encloses $E$, with $C_k = C$ in the case of Gelfand's limit
$$
r_0 = \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \left\| \left(\mathbf{A}^{-1}\right)^k \right\|^{\frac{1}{k}}.
$$

My questions therefore are:

1. Is this approach a valid one as described?
2. If so, what knowledge is there on the rate of convergence of Gelfand's limit, or better still, the error bounds, in terms of $k$, $\|\cdot\|$ and the form of $\mathbf{A}$?  And therefore,
3. Is there an optimal matrix norm that achieves minimal error bound given the particular form of $\mathbf{A}$?

Comment: You are basically asking for the smallest eigenvalue. Some approaches are described here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/271864/617446

Comment: Have come across this:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379509003590?ref=pdf_download&fr=RR-2&rr=74372b506f2771e7